# How to add www. to urls in text file

Tags: php, regex

I've got a text file containing a lot of URLs. Some of the URLs start with `www.` and `http://` and some them start with nothing.

I want to add `www.` in front of every line in the text file where the URL does not start with `www.` or `http://`.

```
$lines = file("sites.txt");

foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(substr($line, 0, 3) != "www" && substr($line, 0, 7) != "http://" ) {

    }
}
```

That's the code I have right now. I know it's not much, but I have no clue how to add `www.` in front of every unmatched line.

Comment: Please show the code you already have, so we can extend it by the if statement you want.

Comment: Instead of just asking how to do it, can you show what you have already tried?

Comment: What regular expression have you tried?

Comment: please add the data of textfile in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will add the `www.` if not present and it will work if there is http/**httpS** in the found line.

```
$url = preg_replace("#http(s)?://(?:www\.)?#","http\\1://www.", $url);
```

This regex will work on the following:

> domain.ext -> http://www.domain.ext
>    www.domain.ext -> http://www.domain.ext
>   http://www.domain.ext -> http://www.domain.ext
>    https://domain.ext -> https://www.domain.ext  (note the httpS)
>    https://www.domain.ext -> https://www.domain.ext  (note the httpS)

---

Regex explained:
`http(s)?://` -> The http's S might not be there, save in case it is.
`(?:www\.)?` ->  the `www.` might not be there. Don't save (`?:`), we're gonna add it anyways

Then we use the `\\1` in the replace value to allow the http**S** to stay working when present.
**Also, all the string `substr` functions will fail on https, because it's 1 character longer.**

Comment: Made it an all-regex solution.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to pass `$lines` by reference so you will be able to alter them:

```
foreach($lines as &$line) { // note the  '&'

    // http:// and www. is missing:
    if(stripos($line, 'http://www.') === false) {
        $line = 'http://www.' . $line;

    // only http:// is missing:
    } elseif(stripos($line, 'http://www.') !== false && stripos($line, 'http://') === false) {
        $line = 'http://' . $line;

    // only www. is missing:
    } elseif(stripos($line, 'http://') !== 0 && stripos($line, 'www.') !== 0)
        $line = 'http://www.' . str_replace('http://', '', $line);

    // nothing is missing:
    } else {
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Simply adding `www.` to a non-www domain can be wrong because `www.example.com` and `example.com` CAN have completely different contents, different servers, different destination, different DNS mapping. It's good to add `http://` but not to add `www.`.

To write the new array back to the file, you'd use:

```
file_put_contents(implode(PHP_EOL, $lines), 'sites.txt');
```

Comment: Would this also replace the line in the text file?

Comment: @user3552670 no, but updated using `file_put_contents`

Comment: This will fail the moment you have a httpS entry. Might not be a problem, just a note.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = file("/var/www/vhosts/mon.totalinternetgroup.nl/public/sites/sites.txt");
$new_lines = array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(substr($line, 0, 3) != "www" || substr($line, 0, 7) != "http://" ) {
       $new_lines[] = "www.".$line;
    }else{
       $new_lines[] = $line;  
    }
}

$content = implode("\n", $new_lines);
file_put_contents("/var/www/vhosts/mon.totalinternetgroup.nl/public/sites/sites.txt", $content);
```

Comment: Would this also replace the line in the text file?

Answer (score 0):

use this:
with only 3 line!

```
<?
    $g0 = file_get_contents("site");
    #--------------------------------------------------
    $g1 = preg_replace("#^http://#m","",$g0);
    $g2 = preg_replace("/^www\./m","",$g1);
    $g3 = preg_replace("/^/m","http://",$g2);
    #--------------------------------------------------
    file_put_contents("site2",$g3);
?>
```

input file

```
1.com
www.d.som
http://ss.com
http://www.ss.com
```

output file:

```
http://1.com
http://d.som
http://ss.com
http://ss.com
```

Comment: You regex, but don;t use the power of regex. Instead you run the slow regex-functionality 3 times to do a hair more then basic string replace functions....

Comment: @Martijn : But understand it is easy for beginners!!

Comment: Heheh, I disagree, but alternative solutions can be a good thing. This will be mega-slow on large files.

Comment: Fast code for large operations, not the code that is't run more than once!!